# React - How to forward requests to routes that are not listed in the Router to a NotFound (404) component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the Router :

```
   <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar />
          {/* <Landing /> */}
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <section className="containerSpecial">
            <Alert />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/forgot-my-password" component={ForgotMyPassword}/>{" "}
              <Route exact path="/reset-password" component={ResetPassword} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />{" "}

               ... More PrivateRoutes


              // Another route that forwards to "NotFound" Component
            </Switch>
          </section>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
```

When the user hits a url like `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` or any other url from the 
listed above , is being forward to the corresponding component.
However when users hit `http://localhost:3000/ddlksajldsajk` or `http://localhost:3000/dashboard1`
nothing is being rendered.

How can I forward urls that are not listed to a `NotFound` component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new route like this as the very last route:

```
<Route path='/' component={my404Component} />
```

Notice it does not have exact. Anything that hasn't been matched will match with it and send them to the 404.

Answer (score 3):

just add  `<Route component={NoMatch} />` :

```
 <Router>
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      {/* <Landing /> */}
      <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
      <section className="containerSpecial">
        <Alert />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/forgot-my-password" component={ForgotMyPassword}/>{" "}
          <Route exact path="/reset-password" component={ResetPassword} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />{" "}

           ... More PrivateRoutes


          // Another route that forwards to "NotFound" Component
          <Route component={NotFound} /> 
        </Switch>
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  </Router>
```

see [react router handling 404 pages](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-handling-404-pages/)